# Uploaded Image doesn't show as base image in frontend and thumbnail at backend (Magento 2.2.3)

Tags: magento2, product-images, thumbnail

Suddenly I'm having an issue regarding uploaded images. They are on the backend (Images And Videos ) but does not show as a base in frontend and thumbnail at the backend. After uploading an image also, the "upload" option goes missing and I just see a loading gif beside the uploaded image. I've attached images. Do you guys know why it's happening? Could be server issues?

[image: Backend]

[image: Backend]

[image: Backend]

[image: Frontend]

UPDATE: I noticed i got this error "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later." after saving

Comment: Press F12 , look at the Network tab and then check the response from server first

Comment: Can you please check the Image configuration on admin side?
When you set the image at product edit page you can see the six doted button at left upper corner, where you need to specify that the thumbnail image, or base image.
Maybe it will help you

Comment: the role is only image hover on the 2nd website products and as you can see, only the config product dont have thumbnail and the simple ones do have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to adjust the attributes in default, as somewhat it has been changed suddenly. Which I don't know how it happened. Added the attributes to Image and then the roles appeared again.

Answer (score 0):

in image.php file

public function getPath()

```
{
    return $this->getRelativePath($this->context->getPath());
}
```

just replace this 
by this

public function getpath()

{

```
$result = $this->context->getPath();
$result = $this->join($result, $this->getModule());

$result = $this->join($result, $this->getMiscPath());

return $this->join($result, $this->getFilePath());
```

}

Comment: im not sure where to find this file, as i have searched and could not find it. can you pls show where i could exactly find it? tnx